# SWIFTUI and variable old and new way

Tags: swiftui

In the older version of swift 3 I put my variable at the  after the import statetments.   With the new Swiftui is this still a good way.

1) Swift 3

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class pushgroups_vc: BaseViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate, UITextViewDelegate
{


    var dbarray_id: [String] = []
    var dbarray_code: [String] = []
    var dbarray_title: [String] = []
    var dbarray_description: [String] = []
    var dbarray_public: [String] = []
    var dbarray_accesscode: [String] = []
```

2)   Is this still valid
    in Swift 5 xcode 11

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine


let newVars = commonfunc()

var devicetoken:String = ""
var email:String = ""
var password:String = ""

var dbarray_id: [String] = []
var dbarray_subject: [String] = []
var dbarray_body: [String] = []
var dbarray_image: [String] = []
var dbarray_location: [String] = []
var dbarray_start_date: [String] = []
```

Comment: Yes, it's still valid.

Comment: Does it make it global for the whole view? And does adding @State to each help?

Comment: `SwiftUI` is not new version of `swift`, it is just a new swift-based framework, so the question is unrelated.